# How to understand the insights from number of jobs and DAG plotted for this DataFrame operations in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, directed-acyclic-graphs

Below is the DataFrame operation I have written in pyspark interpreter

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([{"id":1,"name":"A"},{"id":2,"name":"B"}])
df.show()
```

when I run the above operations it executes in below flow

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]
[Stage 1:>                                                          (0 + 4) / 4]
[Stage 2:>                                                          (0 + 3) / 3]
```

Below is the completed job list shown:
[image]

DAG shown for first job:

[image]

Please explain me how the number of jobs shown are 3 and how different operations like parallelize,mapPartitions,map gets added to DAG with just 2 operations done in dataframe